# My project runs in simulator fine but gives link error with device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I get the following link warning for every framework that I have included if I try to run it using the actual iphone device but it works fine with the simulator:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKIT.framework/UIKIT,
>   file was built for unsupported file format which is not the
>   architecture being linked (armv7)

I get the same error for Foundation, CoreGraphics, etc.

It used to work on both platforms fine with the same Storekit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning says you're trying to link Simulator SDK's framework when compiling for device. Not sure why, try relinking StoreKit in project settings. Also, make sure you're compiling for right architecture or just build a fat binary.

Comment: Are there suppose to be two different StoreKit's for simulator and device?  This runs in simulator fine and it was running on device fine until I added reachability feature.  I did not touch anythig related to StoreKit.  under architecture it says armv6 and armv7.  Is that ok?

Comment: armv6 and armv7 are both good. That covers you for 3G and 3GS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of the OS you are targeting, you may need to include other frameworks to make sure you get all of them. In your architecture, make sure you have armv6 armv7 and i386 included so it will build and run properly in the simulator as well as any devices you may run it on.

Comment: I just found out I get this warning for all frameworks, UIKIT, Foundation, CoreGraphics, etc.  Everything used to work and all of a sudden I am seeing this.  Any idea?

Comment: Your error looks like it is on just the StoreKit framework. Are you trying to build for a version that doesn't support it? Odd that it would work in simulator but not on device. What device and OS version are you trying to run it on?

Comment: It is on all frameworks.  Actually I removed StoreKit and now the warnings are on the rest of the frameworks:  For device I am using iPhone(4.2.1, overriding Base SDK TO 4.3).  MY OS IS 10.6.8.  I should mention that everything was fine yesterday.  I did not change anything in frameworks and this happened.

Comment: Try to clean your build. Rebuild and see. I'm out of ideas I'm afraid. I sympathize, I've had odd issues like this in XCode as well. Keep grinding.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  This is really frustrating.  You suggested to clean the build.  What steps should I take to do that?  Thanks

Comment: Under your build options, there is an option to Clean. No guarantees, but purges out all your compiles, forces XCode to recompile everything.